# Freemarker utf-8 encoding problems on t.page

Tags: java, html, spring, utf-8, freemarker

I'm having problems with inside pages. It simply are recognizing pages as iso, but I want utf-8, I'm declaring it as default charset. I tried some modifications on freemarker configuration, but they are not having effect.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
</bean>
```

template.html

```
<#macro page>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cemitério - Prefeitura Municipal de Maringá</title>
</head>

<body>
Usuários
<#nested/>
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

login.html

```
<#import "templates/template.html" as t/>

<@t.page>

<#if erroLogin??>
    ${erroLogin}
</#if>
<form action="entrar" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Usuário:</label>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" />
        <br />
        <label>Senha:</label>
        <input type="text" name="senha" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </div>
</form>

</@t.page>
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the accents were all right in the inserted variables, yet the accents entered directly into the templates weren't, and the browser seems to know that the page uses UTF-8 (that you can check in the page information dialog of the browser), either:

- The template file was saved with the wrong encoding. In Eclipse, you should go to Window -> Preferences -> Workspace, and set text file encoding to UTF-8. This is a global setting, but by default Eclipse uses the platform default, which doesn't make sense in 99% of the projects. You can also set this on project level under Project -> Properties -> Resource.
- FreeMarker has used wrong charset to decode the template files, as it also uses the platform default by default. So you should set the `default_encoding` setting to `UTF-8`. You can also force the encoding in the template with `<#ftl encoding='UTF-8'>`.

Answer (score 1):

how about if you add this charset="UTF-8"

```
<label charset="UTF-8" >Usuário:</label>
```

in HTML 5 you would add:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in previous HTML (notice you have lower case in your code..maybe that might be contributing to it)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: how about this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"> ... according to this site (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp) The first 256 characters of Unicode character-sets correspond to the 256 characters of ISO-8859-1. this may not be a best solution but may at least some kind of workaround

Comment: And it's funny, because the bean content ${user.name} that is called inside <@t.page>... </@t.page> print the accents correctly...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I need to create the login.html file again, using dreamweaver, then save as html and paste the file on the eclipse project.

Comment: Just set the default encoding to UTF-8 in Eclipse. It uses the platform default otherwise...

Comment: Please, post this as a answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you might want to encode entities. If you are working with a Java object as the data (context) for your template you could add a method there to encode entities:

```
public String htmlEntities(String input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '"') {
            sb.append("&quot;");
        }
        else if (c == '<') {
            sb.append("&lt;");
        }
        else if (c == '>') {
            sb.append("&gt;");
        }
        else if (c < 128) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        else {
            sb.append(String.format("&#x%04x;", (int) c));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This can be used in your template like:

```
${htmlEntities('Usuário')}
```

The result will be:

```
Usu&#x00e1;rio
```

Answer (score 0):

I configured Freemarker using a Bean and set default encoding to UTF-8:

```java
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import freemarker.cache.ClassTemplateLoader;
...

@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {
...

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerClassLoaderConfig() {
        final var configuration = new freemarker.template.Configuration(
                freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31);
        configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        final var freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setConfiguration(configuration);
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
}
```